# Folder of Build is not coming in Gradle Tasks in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am new to Gradle , I have imported an existing Gradle project but folder of "build" Gradle Project is not coming in Gradle Tasks. I have added jdk path in both my eclipse.ini and gradle.properties. Please let me know of any configuration is left so that I can get build option directly. I am referring to this tutorial https://qaautomation.expert/2021/05/02/how-to-create-java-gradle-project-in-eclipse/

[image]

As suggested by someone in comment section I have untick the Gradle Build option from project explorer but it is still now working.

[image]

eclipse.ini

```
-vm
C:\Users\xyz\jdk-17.0.2\bin\javaw.exe
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Users/xyz/jdk-17.0.2
```

Comment: The Gradle build folder is hidden by default. In the _Project Explorer_ view (you screenshot is cropped so the view to the left can also the _Package Explorer_ which would be different), click the filter icon and disable _Gradle build folder_.

Comment: @howlger I did that still build folder is not showing. I refreshed the project and restarted eclipse also but still it is not coming.

Comment: You did what? Please show a not cropped screenshot vs. the Gradle build folder in the Windows Explorer (right-click project folder and choose _Show In > System Explorer_).

Comment: @howlger I added screenshot in question now also I am using gradle 8.5 with java 17 can that be an issue?

Comment: Your project structure is at least uncommon and different to the tutorial you referring to: `build.gradle` is not in the project folder, but nested in a folder named `source` (it is unclear to me how you did this and I cannot reproduce it). So please check in the Windows Explorer whether and where the build folder has been created. In Step 5 it is important to choose the Gradle version 6.6 since the project structure for `java-library` has changed in higher versions (also explained in the referred tutorial).

Comment: I solved this by doing 2 things adding eclipse plugin in build.gradle and starting eclipse uisng command then run from cmd--> gradle eclipse