# Gradle Tasks not loading in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am new to Gradle , I have imported one existing Gradle project in Eclipse but I am not getting Gradle Tasks(containing folder Build and others) in eclipse.
I have added jdk path in gradle.properties org.gradle.java.home=C:/Users/xyz/jdk-17.0.2 and using gradle 7.6 version. Also from package explorer I have untick the option of hiding gradle build option. I restarted, refreshed many times but its not loading. Any idea what could be missing?
[image]

Comment: In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78113693/6505250) you have a different, but also strange project structure which I also cannot reproduce. Before you ask questions about the tools you use, please explain the purpose of the two nested Gradle projects and why the outer project is called `source`. Is this really the project structure you want?

Comment: @howlger it is an existing running project , not newly created by me. I am only importing the project. in other although build.gradle was not at root level still gradle tasks were loading(besides Build). I have imported both as Gradle projects.

Comment: Can you check the `Error Log` view?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying it is getting build via cmd but in eclipse I am not getting build option.. no ERROR in error log only warning..

Comment: I guess right clicking on the project and selecting `Gradle`>`Refresh Project` doesn't do anything? Does that sshow errors in the console?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying no it doesn't.. i restarted eclipse also.. only warnings

Comment: buildsetup , help, ide folders are coming but not build..

Comment: @dan1stiscrying my gradle-wrapper . properties contains this distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
can this be an issue ? for local build should this be changed?

Comment: This is not what I asked. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I solved this by doing 2 things adding eclipse plugin in build.gradle and starting eclipse uisng command then run from cmd--> gradle eclipse