# Lombok not generating Getters and setters in Gradle Project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, lombok

I am using lombok + Gradle in my Spring boot application. I have installed Lombok plugin from marketplace and the same version I have mentioned in my build.gradle but still in my model class I am getting a warning that generate getters and setters and also other classes not able to access the getters and setters. I have also added lombok.config in my root folder with lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true. I am not sure which config I am missing?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}


version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
// annotation processors
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

Bean

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing ?

[image]

Comment: You have two open questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78113693/6505250) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78114863/6505250) to which you stop responding, although they are still unclear and not reproducible. Please consider to improve them and answer them yourself (obviously you have found a solution yourself, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this new question) or to delete them before you ask new questions. According to your new question, it's highly recommended to follow the Lombok documentation here: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: It depends whether you run your application build with Gradle or from within Eclipse (using the Eclipse own incremental Java compiler and which requies the Eclipse Lombok plugin). For the second case, be aware that the Lombok plugin has known issues for the current Eclipse version, e.g. [here](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3621).

Comment: @howlger I have added the steps which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @howlger for lettingme know pblm with the lombok plugin. I followed this tutorial and its working for me now https://www.folio3.ai/blog/how-to-install-lombok-java-eclipse-gradle/